# Dockerfile for Go and chromedp

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, chromedp

I'm trying to implement a Dockerfile to contain both my go binary and also chromedp. I manage to build the image and I can run the image and the go binary runs as expected, all but chromedp.

Thanks in advance!

Error message i recieve:
`Error exec: "google-chrome": executable file not found in $PATH running chromedp`

### Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1


##
## Build
##
FROM golang:1.17-bullseye as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN go build -o /docker-scraper

EXPOSE 8080

FROM chromedp/headless-shell:latest

CMD ["/docker-scraper"]

##
## Deploy
##
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /docker-scraper /docker-scraper

EXPOSE 8080

USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-scraper"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error exec: "google-chrome": executable file not found in $PATH running chromedp

This is because you did not run your go program in `chromedp/headless-shell`. You define `multi-stage builds`, but with this, only the last stage will be act as the base image of final image.

This means your go program in fact runs in `gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11`, not `headless-shell`.

To learn how to run your own program in `headless-shell`, you could refers to its [official document](https://github.com/chromedp/docker-headless-shell#using-as-a-base-image):

> When using chromedp/headless-shell as a base image to build an image that runs your own program, You could experience zombie process problem. To reap zombie processeses, use dumb-init or tini on your Dockerfile's ENTRYPOINT
>
> ```
> FROM chromedp/headless-shell:latest
> ...
> # Install dumb-init or tini
> RUN apt install dumb-init
> # or RUN apt install tini
> ...
> ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
> # or ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]
> CMD ["/path/to/your/program"]
> ```

A minimal workable example as next.

**main.go:**

```
package main

import (
        "context"
        "log"
        "fmt"
        "time"

        "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
        ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(
                context.Background(),
                chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf),
        )
        defer cancel()

        ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, 15*time.Second)
        defer cancel()

        err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
                chromedp.Navigate(`https://golang.org/pkg/time/`),
        )
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("done")
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM golang:latest as build

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY ./main.go .
RUN go mod init docker-scraper; go mod tidy
RUN go build

FROM chromedp/headless-shell:latest
RUN apt-get update; apt install dumb-init -y
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
COPY --from=build /go/src/app/docker-scraper /tmp
CMD ["/tmp/docker-scraper"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  goservice:
    build: .
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker-compose up
Recreating chromedp-docker_goservice_1 ... done
Attaching to chromedp-docker_goservice_1
goservice_1  | done
chromedp-docker_goservice_1 exited with code 0
```

You could see no error about `google-chrome` now.

Comment: Perfect, works flawless. Thanks alot for super good answer!